# custom radio button image selection

Tags: html, css, radio-button

Im trying to customise radio buttons but having a little problem. The image comes up correctly, however it doesn't allow me to select a radio button, therefore the image sprite does no move along (to the selected image).

When I change the css for the radio button to (turn the display back on) :

```
input[type="radio"]
{

}
```

The radio button appears (as well as the images), when I click the radio button to selected, the images do change size, however the whole point of this is to have no default radio button but just the images.

HTML

```
   <div class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" id="" name="tester"/><label for=""><span></span>Button 1</label>
   </div>
       <div class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" id="Radio3" name="tester"/><label for=""><span class="label-font"></span>Button 2</label>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.radio-inline
{
   margin-bottom:15px;
}

input[type="radio"]
{
    display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:200;  
}


input[type="radio"] + label span
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(../images/radio-btn.png) left top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;    
}

input[type="radio"]:checked
{
    background:url(../images/radio-btn.png) -40px top no-repeat;
{
```

Comment: Ive used this and its extremely customizable : http://www.screwdefaultbuttons.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the CSS.  This definitely won't help matters.

```
input[type="radio"]:checked
{
    background:url(../images/radio-btn.png) -40px top no-repeat;
{  /** Should be } **/
```

Answer (score 0):

Error in the CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked
{
    background:url(../images/radio-btn.png) -40px top no-repeat;
{
```

Should change to

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span
{
    background:url(../images/radio-btn.png) -40px top no-repeat;
}
```

I added '+ label span' and also the last bracket was the wrong way round.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/* 
    Hide the original radios and checkboxes
    (but still accessible)

    :not(#foo) > is a rule filter to block browsers
                 that don't support that selector from
                 applying rules they shouldn't

*/
li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='radio'], 
li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='checkbox'] {

    /* Hide the input, but have it still be clickable */
    opacity: 0;

    float: left;
    width: 18px;
}


li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='radio'] + label,
li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='checkbox'] + label {
    margin: 0;
    clear: none;

    /* Left padding makes room for image */
    padding: 5px 0 4px 24px;

    /* Make look clickable because they are */
    cursor: pointer;

    background: url(off.png) left center no-repeat; 
}

/*
    Change from unchecked to checked graphic
*/
li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='radio']:checked + label {
    background-image: url(radio.png);
}
li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='checkbox']:checked + label {
    background-image: url(check.png);
}
```

See more here: http://www.wufoo.com/2011/06/13/custom-radio-buttons-and-checkboxes/

Or check out this CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azFfK

Answer (score 0):

The below will work out for you i guess.
you can use any type of images for each and every state. 
the below sample is done for radio button and checkbox.

you can also find the sass solution in github: https://github.com/lpradhap/Awesome-Checkbox-and-radio-button

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
body {
  padding: 100px;
}

/* checkbox and radio buttion */
label {
  display: inline-block
}

label input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  float: left
}

label input[type="checkbox"] + span {
  background-image: url("http://pradhap.com/demo/awesome-check-radio/images/control-sprite.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 -40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -mozkit-apperance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0
}

label input[type="checkbox"] + span:hover {
  background-position: 0 -80px
}

label input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + span {
  background-position: 0px -60px
}

label input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
  background-position: 0 0px
}

label input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:hover {
  background-position: 0 -20px
}

label input[type="radio"] {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  float: left
}

label input[type="radio"] + span {
  background-image: url("http://pradhap.com/demo/awesome-check-radio/images/control-sprite.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -22px -40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -mozkit-apperance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0
}

label input[type="radio"]:disabled + span {
  background-position: -22px -60px
}

label input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
  background-position: -22px 0px
}

label input[type="radio"]:checked + span:hover {
  background-position: -22px -20px
}

label:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}

label:hover input[type="checkbox"] + span {
  background-position: 0 -80px
}

label:hover input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + span {
  background-position: 0px -60px
}

label:hover input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
  background-position: 0 -20px
}

label:hover input[type="radio"] + span {
  background-position: -22px -80px
}

label:hover input[type="radio"]:disabled + span {
  background-position: -22px -60px
}

label:hover input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
  background-position: -22px -20px
}


/* dropdown  */
select {
  width: 268px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 34px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
}
select option {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="text-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="test-checkbox" id="text-checkbox" />
            <span></span>
            Sample Check box
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="test-radio">
            <input type="radio" name="test-radio" id="test-radio" />
            <span></span>
            Sample radio button
        </label>
        <label for="test-radio1">
            <input type="radio" name="test-radio" id="test-radio1" />
            <span></span>
            Sample radio button
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```